# Is $C_0(\mathbb R)$ separable?

Tags: analysis

Let $C_0$ be the Banach space of all continuous real value functions whose limits in $\pm \infty$ is zero, with the supremum norm. Is this space separable?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are continuous bijections between $\Bbb R$ and $(-1, 1)$. One example is
$$
h(x) = \frac{2}{\pi}\arctan(x)
$$
This means there is an isometry between your space and the space of continuous, real valued functions $f$ on $(-1, 1)$ with $\lim_{x \to -1^+}f(x) = \lim_{x \to 1^-} f(x)= 0$ (still with sup norm). The set of polynomials with rational coefficients (and with $(x^2 - 1)$ as factor) are dense on this space.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, here is a countable dense set:  Functions
$$
p(x)e^{-x^2}
$$
where $p$ is a polynomial with rational coefficients.